# Writing a script to handle iscsi

Tags: bash, scripts

I am currently writing a script that (atleast in theory) should install and add changes in config on iscsitarget, but I keep getting an error that I can't seem to figure out the origin of.

The errors being:

```
line 39: $'[\302\240-e': command not found.
mv: cannot stat `/etc/iet/ietd.conf' : No such file or directory.
```

Here is the code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONF="/etc/default/iscsitarget."
LOGIN="/etc/iet/ietd.conf.back"

#Dette skjekker om bruker er root

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Du må være root for å kjøre dette scriptet."
  exit 1
fi 

#Skjekker om iscsi target er innstallert

dpkg -s "iscsitarget" > /dev/null 2>&1 && {
  echo "Iscsi Target er allerede innstallert."
  } || {
  echo "Innstallerer iscsi target..."
  aptitude -y install iscsitarget
  }

#Her tar vi konfigurasjons filen til og gjør en backup av den

if [ -e "$CONF" ]
  then
    echo "$CONF eksisterer, backup er unødvendig."
  else
    mv /etc/default/iscsitarget /etc/default/iscsitarget.back
    echo "Backup av konfigurasjonsfilen er tatt."
fi

#Her lager vi en ny konfigurasjonsfil til iscsi
cat > /etc/default/iscsitarget <<"EOF"
ISCSITARGET_ENABLE=true
EOF
echo "Konfigurasjonsfil oppdatert!"

#Backup av login fil og login til iscsitarget
if [ -e "$LOGIN" ]
  then
    echo "$LOGIN eksisterer, backup er unødvendig."
  else
    mv /etc/iet/ietd.conf /etc/iet/ietd.conf.back
    echo "Backup av konfigurasjonsfil er tatt."
fi
```

Sort of new to this, thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer, just checked the script with vim and the highlighting dosen't seem out of order, nor can I seem to find where I missed a quote.

Comment: OK, that clarifies that it was an issue with the copying into the question.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. There's no line 45?

Comment: My bad, it is actually line 39 (updated in the OP).

Comment: Could you please put here all output that you see after running this script.

Comment: Yeah, here is all the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkwxn7mh1jfonm7/error.png

Comment: Please check line 39 for any strange characters. Especially if you copy this command from other source. You can accidentally copy some invisible characters

Comment: Heh, that seemed to be it, now I feel foolish. Thanks for all the help you guys :)

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happen when you copy/paste some command from other source, and accidentally copy some **invisible special characters**.

Error usually looks like:

```
line 39: $'[\302\240-e': command not found.
```

Where 0302 0240 is octal UTF-8 for a non-breaking space.

If you are using vi/vim you can check you code using `:set list` command. As it is suggested in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character), you may do this:

```
:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
```

then using `:set list` you will see all invisible characters except whitespaces

Also I recommend you add [shebang](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/shebang.htm) at the top of your script. In your case `#!/bin/bash`.